# Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lokhttp3/internal/ws/WebSocketReader;

Tags: android, android-multidex

I am facing above error of multidex. I have tried to resolved with multiple way as I know and I tried to find similar issues. There is many issues related multidex but all the scenario trying to apply in my code but not resolved my problem.

My Dependencies are as below :

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'

implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.2'
implementation files('libs/client-sdk.aar')
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-alpha1'}
```

I am getting this issue due to WebSocketReader class from multiple dependency as I can understand this issue and it's coming from retrofit. But not sure about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Zoe Thanks for reply , by the way I have tried almost all scenario but not resolved can you please tell me what changes i need to do here?

Comment: have you check `libs/client-sdk.aar` dependency? Probably it contains okhttp. Or check your libs.